# elastic search .NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/manipulation/Filterable

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, junit4

Hello I  used java to connect elastic search I wrote pom that is here:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Logimethods</groupId>
  <artifactId>ElasticResearch</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
      <!-- add the elasticsearch repo -->
      <repository>
         <id>elasticsearch-releases</id>
         <url>https://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases</url>
         <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
         </releases>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </snapshots>
      </repository>

   </repositories>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
   <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
   <version>4.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
   <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
   <version>4.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
   <artifactId>lucene-codecs</artifactId>
   <version>4.7.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
   <artifactId>lucene-test-framework</artifactId>
   <version>4.7.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

then I have main class that is here:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));    
    LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime();

    System.out.println("The current local time is: " + currentTime);
    System.out.println("Safe exit.");


    }

}
```

and finally when I run project I have this erorre:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/manipulation/Filterable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    ...
    at org.elasticsearch.common.Randomness.<clinit>(Randomness.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.<init>(TransportClientNodesService.java:100)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:265)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:130)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:116)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:106)
    at Logimethods.ElasticResearch.App.main(App.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filterable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

I used elasticsearch5.6.4 and java version:1.8
I import all libraries but why there is this error?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, I removed junit from just test scope and the same for a few other dependencies to fix it.